# Restful Web service Authentication and Authorization with Apache Shiro

Tags: apache, web-services, rest, shiro

I am able to authenticate web based application using apache shiro  through databases using JDBC relam. Further more, I am successively able to make the use of Shiro-Filters to grant access for particular  web-resource or http urls using Shiro filter configuation in web.xml and configuration into shiro.ini.

Now, I want to implement the same functionality for the webservices too. In Particular, I want user to hit the login-url for getting the token, if the credentials are valid. And after that, all the successive requests for the webservices has to be validated based on that particular token for the user. 
I have no any clue to  implement this. Any suggestions, procedures,  or suggestive links could help me alot !!

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use  [**jersey**](https://jersey.java.net/) web framwork since it's very simple, in java and annotated!

You specify your uri's, roles, permission in shiro.ini as you know and after that make a web project on jersey.

After that the use in a java code is clear and simple! See how to retrieve

Code in jersey :

```
/**
     * login to app
     * @param username
     * @param password
     * @return
     * since v0.6.4 
     */
    @PUT
    @Path("login")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public Response loginv3(
            @FormParam("username") String username,
            @FormParam("password") String password){

        return login(username, password);
    }
```

In this case we will retrieve the books only if are a user connected and that we have "reader" role :

```
  @GET
    @Path("/books")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    @RequiresUser
    @RequiresRoles("reader")
```

It's realy easy! See the shiro documentation : [shiro annotation reference](https://shiro.apache.org/java-annotations-list.html)

Comment: Hi Jean thank you for your reply ! How the user is authenticated when he tries to access service for get books. How toke it will know that this particular user is logged in ! When he is logged in through the different browser once after getting the token.

Comment: the user is authenticated with shiro. please fork the [shiro example app](https://github.com/lhazlewood/apache-shiro-tutorial-webapp). Give me some feedback please!  :) thanks

Comment: You should never use @QueryParam's to pass user and password for authentication. I can't downvote this answer but this is an insecure approach.

Comment: you're right  @PabloAndrésMartínezVargas my bad, i'm correcting it !

Answer (score 0):

This mecanic is implemented by shiro, the token is passed to the browser and is stored as a cookie on the client navigator. After that shiro will pass the token on each connection to the service thrue the browser.

Try first to have authentication propaged true your application : [authen shiro doc](http://shiro.apache.org/java-authentication-guide.html)

Please implement the [shiro Step by Step project](http://shiro.apache.org/webapp-tutorial.html) in order to validate the concepts of Authentication and of Autorization ! :)

Give me some feedback please. Enjoy it :)

Comment: Can you provide any reference example.. !!

Comment: please git fork this project: [Shiro reference example GIT](https://github.com/lhazlewood/apache-shiro-tutorial-webapp). Give me some feedback

Answer (score -1):

user authentication with shiro is show in [shiro example on GIT](https://github.com/lhazlewood/apache-shiro-tutorial-webapp). Simply fork this git to have it working.

Shiro is passing a cookie in order to keep the connection alive! :) The transfert of the cookie is managed by shiro, you won't have to think of it.

enjoy :)